# On active row select col"A" and change to upper case

Tags: excel

On any selected column using VBA I would like to select whatever is in column “A” and change it to CAPE.
Thanks!

Comment: only column A when you make a selection anywhere in the sheet? Single cell selection? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub caps()
'Change Active row col 'A' to CAPs
'
Cells(ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Row, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = UCase(ActiveCell.Value)

End Sub
```